# Como faz o printf da soma da diagonal de uma matriz

Tags: c, matriz, array-multidimensional, printf

Estou com dificuldades pra criar um `printf` que dependa da entrada. Eu quero que faça o print dependendo de quantos números tem na diagonal de uma matriz e mostre esses números. EXEMPLO:

> Você deve imprimir os valores utilizados para o cálculo do traço e o próprio valor do traço segundo o modelo a seguir:
>
> ```
>  tr(A) = (1.00) + (5.00) + (9.00) = 15.00
> ```
>
> NO CASO ESSA É UMA MATRIZ 3X3, MAS NEM SEMPRE VAI SER

Isso foi o que eu fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
int n=0, soma=0, total=0;

scanf("%d", &n);

int matriz[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
  
    scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    if(i==j){
    total=total+matriz[i][j];
    
    printf("tr(A) = (%d) +....n  = %d", matriz[n][n], total);
    }
  }
}
  



   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se você tem uma matriz quadrada n x n então as diagonais, tanto a primária quanto a secundária, terão n elementos. Para imprimir esta quantidade variável de elementos utilize um loop. (Não entendi o seu exemplo, você não mostrou uma matriz)

Answer (score 1):

Veja se, por acaso, é isto o que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n=0, total=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int matriz[n][n];
    printf("tr(A) =");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
            if(i==j) {
                total += matriz[i][j];
                printf(" %s(%d)", (i==0) ? "" : "+ ", matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo mano, obrigado. Se eu quiser colocar duas casas decimais nas somas eu tenho q trocar por %.2f e trocar o tipo por float?

Comment: consegui aqui mano, valeu msm, ajudou muito

Comment: Sim, troque a declaração da matriz, e total, para float e utilize o formato `%.2f` no printf.

Comment: fiz isso, muito obrigado